# What does 0 stand for in Tensor("decode_jpeg:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=uint8)?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
rgb_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=IMAGE_CHANNELS,name="decode_jpeg")
print "Training image:        ",rgb_image
```

From the above code rgb_image prints the following statement:

```
Tensor("decode_jpeg:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=uint8)
```

I have 200 images in my directory for training.
What does 0 stand for in the above statement? Is it the tensor rank? And why does it return shape(?,?,1). Shouldn't it return the height and width of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` stands for 0th return value of the op `tf.image.decode_jpeg`.
Think about any op as a function that can return an array of `tf.Variables`. Every `op` has a position in this array, starting from 0.

The shape `(?,?,1)` is correct, because during graph creation you don't know anything about the image (except the depth you're passing to the `tf.image.decode_jpeg` op).
The missing information (width and height) are available only at run-time.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.